Pyspark column disappears randomly after applyInPandas
I've been facing an annoying issue that I can't figure out. I have a simple pyspark dataframe which is looking like this:
ID  code    country
T1  AB  United States
T1  unknown United States
T1  BB  United States
T2  BB  United States
T1  unknown United States
T2  unknown United States
T1  BB  United States
...

and this dataframe contains around 6 million rows. My task is to groupby this dataframe by country(which is constant US), and do some magic after summing, counting, etc. the IDs and CODEs. I want to do this in the following way:
df.groupby('country').applyInPandas(func, schema=schema).show()

and the aggregating function is the following:
def func(dfp):

 ids = dfp.groupby('ID').size().reset_index(name='size').rename(columns= {'ID': 'ID_SIZE'}) # this is the line where the error gets thrown, literally first line in the function
 ...

And the error says: 'KeyError: 'ID'". When I print out the data inside the function, it really shows that there is no ID column. And the strange thing is that when I do a random 1% sample of the original data, then it gets executed without problems. So I don't actually understand what is happening under the hood, and where that "ID" column goes. All of the columns has string datatype and none of them contains NULLs.
